# my hyundai vin code is not valid

Tags: hyundai, elantra, vin

I have Hyundai Elantra 2015

My Hyundai VIN code is : `KMHDG41LBEU462988`

And it's not a valid code in https://autoservice.hyundaiusa.com/campaignhome

What should I do? I bought it when I was in a different country. Auto service machine couldn't detect VIN, either.

[image]

Comment: Did you buy it from a dealership ? if so, reach out to them in regards to this.

Comment: Is this number from the car papers or did you read it from it's parts?

Comment: @Mark I add Image of vin code

Comment: The VIN should be located in several places around vehicle. Check and see if it's the same elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't solve your problem with your VIN, I've been researching about this topic because I have similar problem and I've found that the 9th digit is the result of an error-checking algorithm, this means, or at least I understand, that Hyundai or whatever automotive you provide your VIN code, they first checks that digit, calculates checksum and if those two digits doesn't match then the VIN is invalid. Your VIN is invalid because the letter on 9th position is a B and must be a number.

In [this](http://vin.dataonesoftware.com/vin_basics_blog/bid/112040/Use-VIN-Validation-to-Improve-Inventory-Quality) website explains how to calculate that digit that can be a numeric digit 0 through 9 or the letter X in case the algorithm result were 10:

I suppose that there must be another websites where explains how calculate it, but I found that useful.

In your particular case, applying the algorithm:

Your VIN: `KMHDG41LBEU462988`

**First step** (transliteration):

`2  4   8   4   7   4   1   3   2   5   4   4   6   2   9   8   8`

**Second step** (Compute weighted products):

`16 28  48  20  28  12  2   30  0   45  32  28  36  10  36  24  16`

**Third step** (Sum weighted products):

`16+28+48+20+28+12+2+30+0+45+32+28+36+10+36+24+16 = 411`

**Fourth step** (Compute reminder):

`411 MOD 11 = 4`

With that result your *new* VIN would be:

`KMHDG41L4EU462988`

And this is valid on [Campaign Home](https://autoservice.hyundaiusa.com/campaignhome).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't know if this will answer your question, but I wanted to point out the irregularities in the VIN you provided. On [this website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Numbers_(VIN_codes)/Hyundai/VIN_Codes), it gives a breakdown of how the Hyundai VIN should read. Assuming the information is correct on the wiki, I'll show you what I'm seeing.

Looking at how Hyundai does its VIN, I'll point out the inconsistencies:

VIN you provided:  **KMHDG41LBEU462988**

Breakdown:

- Digit 1: **K** - (Geographic Zone) - Korea
- Digit 2: **M** - (Manufacturer) - HMC
- Digit 3: **H** - (Vehicle Type) - Passenger car, MPV, RV
- Digit 4: **D** - (Model Line and Drive Type) - Genesis Coupe 09-Elantra 2001-
- Digit 5: **G** - (Body Type or Trim Level) - GL or GS Accent, 00 – 04; GT Accent, 03 – 05; GLS Accent, 05; = GLS Santa Fe, 07 –
- Digit 6: **4** - (Trim level of Body Type) - 4 door sedan
- Digit 7: **1** - (Restraint System or GVWR) - Active 3-point
- Digit 8: **L** - (Engine Type) - ***1349 cc SOHC Accent, 97-98***
- Digit 9: **B** - (Check Digit) - ***0-9 or X***
- Digit 10: **E** - (Model Year) - ***2014***
- Digit 11: **U** - (Manufacturing Plant Code) - Ulsan, Korea
- Digit 12-17: **462988** - Sequence manufacturing number

As you can see, there seem to be some discrepancies. This would probably be why you are having problems matching it up. Mind you, you may want to go out and check the digits again. The "B" (Digit 9) might just be an "8". The "E" (Digit 10) might just be an "F". I don't know whether you wrote down the code and took it somewhere, or someone else read it for you, but it seems the issue may be a clerical error if this is how you obtained the number. If not, then take it to Hyundai directly and ask them.

Comment: I add image of vin code to question